# Multiple variables in htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want `rando.com/game/basic/1` to point towards `rando.com/game.php?type=basic&id=1`.

What I have so far:

```
#Fix Rewrite
Options -Multiviews

# Mod Rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^game/([^/]+)/([^\.]+)\$ /game.php?type=$1&id=$2
```

This isn't working. I get a 404 error.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: And what is the wrong with it? It is not working or something 'strange' happens?

Comment: @iCore Correct, it is not working. I get a 404 error.

Comment: Maybe that backslash before the `$` sign? Try this: `^game/([^/]+)/([^.]+)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just go the typical way that some MVC frameworks do and just trim & explode the url in php like so? :

in htaccess redirect to just `game.php?url=$1`

```
$url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'); // to prevent empty array values caused by trailing slash
$url = explode('/', $url);
```

You would end up with type in $url[0] and id in $url[1].
If you're going to accept only numbers and letters you could write that htaccess line like so:

```
RewriteRule ^game/([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ /game.php?url=$1
```

Comment: Good idea. Don't know why I didn't think of this. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome. it also comes in handy, if you ever decide to accept more variables like type=basic id=1 showstats=1 or whatever. you just go on with $url[2] in your php and never look back @htccess file =)

Answer (score 1):

Your rule contains `\$`, which looks for a literal `$`, rather than the end of the string. You want this:

```
RewriteRule ^game/([^/]+)/([^\.]+)$ /game.php?type=$1&id=$2
```